# GCP VM with more than 8 network interfaces

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Is there a solution to have a GCP VM with more than 8 network interfaces as the actual limitation ( https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/quota#per_instance)
Thanks

Comment: The documentation that you reference states: `Unless otherwise noted, these limits cannot be increased`. Limits such as number of network interfaces is a limit of the hypervisor and management software. Those are virtual network interfaces, the underlying hardware has less then eight network interfaces. What is your use case that requires more than eight network interfaces?

Comment: Hello @John, It is about a network appliances (firewall) with more than 8 interfaces

Comment: You are limited to eight network interfaces which cannot be increased for VMs. If you are developing a firewall, contact your Google account manage to discuss dedicated hardware options. If you are a customer, then you do not have any options that I am aware of. Contact your account manager to confirm what is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I post this answer to make solution provided by *@John Hanley* in the comment section more visible:

Accordingly to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/quota#per_instance):

> The following limits apply to VM instances. **Unless otherwise noted, these limits cannot be increased.** For *quotas* relevant to VMs, see [Compute Engine quotas](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#understanding_vm_cpu_and_ip_address_quotas).

[image: quote]

Limits such as number of network interfaces is a limit of the hypervisor and management software. Those are virtual network interfaces, the underlying hardware has less than eight network interfaces.

You are limited to eight network interfaces which cannot be increased for VMs. If you are developing a firewall, contact your Google account manage to discuss dedicated hardware options. If you are a customer, then you do not have any options that I am aware of. Contact your account manager to confirm what is possible.